# Modulo Exponential based on Fermat's little theory?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, fermat-numbers

I come from Computer Science background.

In order to proceed with my question, I want to clarify that we use modular exponential as part of RSA encryption; and please be warned, I'm weak at maths :)

So given the following:
$165^3 \pmod{253}$, how would I be able to compute such a large number like $165^3$? and then mod that to $253$? That's just time-consuming in an exam.

So could anyone please help me with computing this much quicker?

Thanks

Comment: I hope [This](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/388/what-is-the-relation-between-rsa-fermats-little-theorem) will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$253=11\cdot23$$

Now $165\equiv0\pmod{11}$

$165\equiv4\pmod{23}\implies165^2\equiv4^2\pmod{23}$

$\implies165^2\cdot165\equiv4^2\cdot165\pmod{23\cdot165}$

$\equiv16\cdot165\pmod{23\cdot11}$

Comment: Respected bhattacharjee, could you please clarify this section `165^2 ⋅ 165 ≡ 4^2 ⋅ 165 (mod 23 ⋅ 165)`

Comment: Also the last line produces 28, which Im afraid is the not the answer, I believe I should get 110

Comment: @S.Nas, $$a\equiv b\pmod m\implies a\cdot c\equiv b\cdot c\pmod{m\cdot c}$$  and $$16*165\%253=110$$

Comment: Thank you for explaining it :)